# Buffer wrong generation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, buffer

I have a polyline projected in WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_21S:

```
u'MULTILINESTRING ((421451.00299999956 6350629.8709000004, 421439.96719999984 6350607.6084000003, 421428.77199999988 6350605.3015999999, 421423.3515999997 6350581.9752000002, 421422.61209999956 6350557.5774999997, 421420.98249999993 6350527.6290999996, 421422.11170000024 6350503.2463999996, 421422.31549999956 6350477.7474999996, 421422.51040000003 6350453.3573000003, 421422.70529999956 6350428.9670000002, 421421.97460000031 6350403.4606999997, 421422.19610000029 6350375.7445, 421421.5186999999 6350343.5862999996, 421421.74899999984 6350314.7615, 421422.86060000025 6350292.5959999999, 421423.0820000004 6350264.8798000002, 421423.31240000017 6350236.0549999997, 421422.59949999955 6350208.3313999996, 421422.82100000046 6350180.6151999999, 421422.14360000007 6350148.4568999996, 421423.31709999964 6350118.5308999997, 421434.74210000038 6350092.0130000003, 421449.79810000025 6350078.8287000004, 421455.3953999998 6350079.9820999997, 421454.32820000034 6350096.6043999996, 421452.18499999959 6350130.9574999996, 421451.10890000034 6350148.6884000003, 421450.09480000008 6350158.6586999996, 421449.93539999984 6350178.6144000003, 421450.67489999998 6350203.0120999999, 421450.53320000041 6350220.7504000003, 421450.39149999991 6350238.4888000004, 421451.21079999954 6350252.9086999996, 421451.06020000018 6350271.7556999996, 421450.91849999968 6350289.4939999999, 421450.77680000011 6350307.2324000001, 421450.59970000014 6350329.4052999998, 421451.37469999958 6350349.3684, 421452.16739999969 6350367.1141999997, 421452.97780000046 6350382.6426999997, 421451.89279999956 6350401.4823000003, 421451.71569999959 6350423.6551999999, 421451.56520000007 6350442.5022, 421451.39690000005 6350463.5664999997, 421452.18960000016 6350481.3123000003, 421452.9645999996 6350501.2753999997, 421452.81410000008 6350520.1223999998, 421453.58910000045 6350540.0855, 421454.34640000015 6350562.2659, 421454.1958999997 6350581.1129000001, 421454.06309999991 6350597.7426000005, 421461.49409999978 6350603.3454999998, 421484.89850000013 6350597.9888000004, 421486.02770000044 6350573.6059999997, 421486.18699999992 6350553.6503999997, 421486.34630000032 6350533.6947999997, 421485.58899999969 6350511.5143999998, 421484.82270000037 6350490.4425999997, 421485.01750000007 6350466.0524000004, 421484.25129999965 6350444.9807000002, 421484.5521999998 6350407.2867000001, 421484.75580000039 6350381.7878, 421483.98959999997 6350360.7160999998, 421484.14900000021 6350340.7604, 421483.33849999961 6350325.2319, 421483.49789999984 6350305.2763, 421482.74050000031 6350283.0959000001, 421481.96549999993 6350263.1327999998, 421482.12480000034 6350243.1771, 421482.33729999978 6350216.5696, 421481.57110000029 6350195.4978, 421480.8049999997 6350174.4260999998, 421481.86330000032 6350158.9124999996, 421481.15029999986 6350131.1887999997, 421481.31850000005 6350110.1244999999, 421481.48670000024 6350089.0602000002, 421482.55379999988 6350072.4380000001, 421488.35470000003 6350048.0925000003, 421490.25 6350044.7814999996, 421493.07959999982 6350041.4779000003, 421495.90930000041 6350038.1743999999, 421498.72119999956 6350037.0881000003, 421502.45859999955 6350037.1179999998, 421505.27940000035 6350034.9230000004, 421508.08239999972 6350034.9453999996, 421511.80209999997 6350037.1924999999, 421513.65319999959 6350039.4248000002, 421510.62880000006 6350067.1185999997, 421511.32430000044 6350097.0595000004, 421512.08160000015 6350119.2399000004, 421512.82129999995 6350143.6376, 421511.71879999992 6350164.6944000004, 421512.48500000034 6350185.7662000004, 421513.24239999987 6350207.9466000004, 421513.0831000004 6350227.9022000004, 421513.84929999989 6350248.9740000004, 421513.69010000024 6350268.9296000004, 421512.54330000002 6350295.5296999998, 421512.40170000028 6350313.2680000002, 421512.26900000032 6350329.8976999996, 421513.04409999959 6350349.8607999999, 421512.87600000016 6350370.9250999996, 421513.65110000037 6350390.8881999999, 421514.4084999999 6350413.0685999999, 421515.17470000032 6350434.1403999999, 421514.97119999956 6350459.6392000001, 421514.79430000018 6350481.8121999996, 421514.67040000018 6350497.3332000002, 421514.50229999982 6350518.3975, 421514.32529999968 6350540.5703999996, 421514.15720000025 6350561.6347000003, 421514.94120000023 6350580.4891999997, 421517.62939999998 6350594.9238999998, 421540.01979999989 6350599.5374999996, 421545.69699999969 6350590.7130000005, 421545.89159999974 6350566.3228000002, 421546.01539999992 6350550.8016999997, 421547.14439999964 6350526.4189999998, 421547.32129999995 6350504.2460000003, 421547.49820000026 6350482.0730999997, 421547.60429999977 6350468.7693999996, 421547.63970000017 6350464.3348000003, 421548.71559999976 6350446.6039000005, 421547.81659999955 6350442.1617999999, 421547.08559999987 6350416.6555000003, 421546.31929999962 6350395.5838000001, 421546.48730000015 6350374.5195000004, 421545.7209999999 6350353.4478000002, 421545.88910000026 6350332.3835000005, 421545.13159999996 6350310.2030999996, 421544.35639999993 6350290.2400000002, 421544.39180000033 6350285.8054, 421543.61670000013 6350265.8422999997, 421544.71030000038 6350245.8941000002, 421543.91739999969 6350228.1482999995, 421544.08550000004 6350207.0839999998, 421544.26240000036 6350184.9111000001, 421544.41280000005 6350166.0641000001, 421544.57199999969 6350146.1084000003, 421544.68699999992 6350131.6960000005, 421544.83739999961 6350112.8490000004, 421540.30709999986 6350095.0734000001, 421545.07620000001 6350082.9155000001, 421565.49949999992 6350099.7092000004, 421574.63970000017 6350125.2827000003, 421574.52479999978 6350139.6951000001, 421574.36560000014 6350159.6507000001, 421574.18869999982 6350181.8236999996, 421574.02960000001 6350201.7792999996, 421574.76939999964 6350226.1770000001, 421574.61029999983 6350246.1326000001, 421575.37660000008 6350267.2044000002, 421573.27799999993 6350296.0142999999, 421572.96850000042 6350334.8169, 421572.8004999999 6350355.8811999997, 421573.56689999998 6350376.9528999999, 421573.39890000038 6350398.0171999997, 421573.20440000016 6350422.4073999999, 421574.89630000014 6350444.5953000002, 421573.82050000038 6350462.3262, 421574.57799999975 6350484.5066, 421575.33559999987 6350506.6869000001, 421575.15880000032 6350528.8598999996, 421575.91629999969 6350551.0401999997, 421576.69159999955 6350571.0033, 421577.50219999999 6350586.5318, 421586.76669999957 6350596.5842000004, 421599.84850000031 6350596.6885000002, 421605.63169999979 6350574.5602000002, 421606.69859999977 6350557.9380000001, 421606.81350000016 6350543.5256000003, 421607.01680000033 6350518.0267000003, 421607.16700000037 6350499.1797000002, 421607.33499999996 6350478.1153999995, 421606.58619999979 6350454.8263999997, 421607.67960000038 6350434.8782000002, 421608.77309999987 6350414.9299999997, 421608.94099999964 6350393.8657999998, 421608.20990000013 6350368.3594000004, 421608.36899999995 6350348.4038000004, 421607.73510000017 6350310.7023999998, 421607.89419999998 6350290.7467, 421607.11890000012 6350270.7835999997, 421607.31340000033 6350246.3934000004, 421607.47250000015 6350226.4378000004, 421606.69720000029 6350206.4747000001, 421599.36369999964 6350188.6766999997, 421604.20349999983 6350167.6497, 421620.90720000025 6350182.1962000001, 421631.07039999962 6350196.6904999996, 421635.67150000017 6350205.5969000002, 421636.50870000012 6350217.7994999997, 421635.48599999957 6350228.8784999996, 421635.3004999999 6350252.1601, 421635.16789999977 6350268.7898000004, 421635.94330000039 6350288.7528999997, 421636.57720000017 6350326.4543000003, 421636.40050000045 6350348.6272, 421636.21499999985 6350371.9088000003, 421636.14429999981 6350380.7779999999, 421636.11780000012 6350384.1039000005, 421636.84020000044 6350410.7188999997, 421637.61550000031 6350430.682, 421637.45650000032 6350450.6376, 421636.36309999973 6350470.5857999995, 421636.15110000037 6350497.1933000004, 421636.90000000037 6350520.4823000003, 421637.69299999997 6350538.2280999999, 421638.54789999966 6350548.2133999998, 421658.13499999978 6350552.8043, 421657.31549999956 6350538.3843999999, 421658.35580000002 6350525.0881000003, 421662.17289999966 6350515.1401000004, 421671.21829999983 6350435.3844999997, 421670.51360000018 6350406.5522999996, 421670.54009999987 6350403.2264, 421670.55769999977 6350401.0091000004, 421670.62839999981 6350392.1398999998, 421670.65490000043 6350388.8139000004, 421670.71669999976 6350381.0533999996, 421670.74320000038 6350377.7275, 421669.83530000038 6350374.3941000002, 421669.86180000007 6350371.0681999996, 421669.87939999998 6350368.8509, 421669.91480000038 6350364.4162999997, 421670.89329999965 6350358.8805, 421670.92860000022 6350354.4458999997, 421670.02070000023 6350351.1124999998, 421670.99039999954 6350346.6853999998, 421671.01690000016 6350343.3594000004, 421671.05229999963 6350338.9249, 421670.14439999964 6350335.5915000001, 421669.43960000016 6350306.7592000002, 421665.81689999998 6350292.3169999998, 421655.65350000001 6350277.8227000004, 421666.9896999998 6350262.3909999998, 421679.99149999954 6350272.4730000002, 421692.93149999995 6350290.3156000003, 421697.4709999999 6350306.9824999999, 421696.27180000022 6350340.2344000004, 421697.0736999996 6350356.8716000002, 421693.1595999999 6350379.0147000002, 421684.61770000029 6350395.5774999997, 421676.97479999997 6350416.5822000001, 421671.20949999988 6350436.4932000004, 421673.88019999955 6350453.1452000001, 421698.11270000041 6350461.0992000001, 421717.94680000003 6350434.6479000002, 421724.62880000006 6350416.9616999999, 421728.48990000039 6350401.4704, 421720.29220000003 6350374.7959000003, 421695.04609999992 6350376.8123000003, 421687.48269999959 6350387.8393000001, 421677.00129999965 6350413.2562999995, 421672.13509999961 6350437.6092999997, 421685.04879999999 6350458.7778000003, 421698.99409999978 6350467.7585000005, 421697.90079999994 6350487.7067, 421705.2966 6350497.7440999998, 421718.36930000037 6350498.9568999996, 421727.7751000002 6350491.2707000002, 421727.91629999969 6350473.5323999999, 421728.09279999975 6350451.3594000004, 421728.37509999983 6350415.8827999998, 421730.43809999991 6350391.5073999995, 421725.90730000008 6350373.7319, 421719.4637000002 6350361.4846999999, 421722.36390000023 6350349.3119000001, 421740.03780000005 6350359.4309999999, 421754.87330000009 6350373.9623999996, 421759.32469999976 6350401.7156999996, 421758.26680000033 6350417.2293999996, 421758.12569999974 6350434.9676999999, 421758.91009999998 6350453.8221000005, 421759.71219999995 6350470.4592000004, 421758.65429999959 6350485.9729000004, 421766.9757000003 6350497.1261999998, 421788.5549999997 6350486.2106999997, 421791.48170000035 6350470.7120000003, 421791.60510000028 6350455.1908999998, 421791.69330000039 6350444.1045000004, 421785.30240000039 6350425.2054000003, 421799.34480000008 6350421.9910000004, 421808.59169999976 6350434.2604, 421860.90890000015 6350435.7850000001, 421865.66009999998 6350425.8443, 421861.11149999965 6350410.2861000001, 421850.03100000042 6350393.5673000002, 421838.01609999966 6350376.8410999998, 421822.29899999965 6350355.6505000005, 421810.27539999969 6350340.0329, 421799.21270000003 6350321.0966999996, 421789.97470000014 6350307.7187000001, 421777.95999999996 6350290.9923, 421765.95419999957 6350273.1573999999, 421752.07969999965 6350255.3075000001, 421740.06520000007 6350238.5811000001, 421725.36230000015 6350207.4199999999, 421718.00210000016 6350192.9480999997, 421699.52660000045 6350166.1918000001, 421687.52109999955 6350148.3567000004, 421677.42850000039 6350124.9933000002, 421672.01659999974 6350100.5584000004, 421666.56950000022 6350080.5581, 421657.46439999994 6350050.5500999996, 421652.95160000026 6350030.5573000005, 421648.44770000037 6350009.4556999998, 421644.94000000041 6349980.6010999996, 421641.31749999989 6349966.1589000002, 421640.55979999993 6349943.9785000002, 421650.9171000002 6349934.0826000003, 421685.54090000037 6349927.7061999999, 421708.92599999998 6349924.5663000001, 421735.13179999962 6349919.2313000001, 421751.97640000004 6349916.0392000005, 421773.51040000003 6349910.6670000004, 421797.82100000046 6349908.6430000002, 421819.35489999969 6349903.2706000004, 421842.73110000044 6349901.2390999999, 421867.94070000015 6349903.6568999998, 421892.25999999978 6349900.5239000004, 421911.93400000036 6349894.0279000001, 421915.67140000034 6349894.0575999999, 421919.4263000004 6349891.8700000001, 421923.18130000029 6349889.6824000003, 421926.92750000022 6349888.6034000004, 421931.60800000001 6349887.5318999998, 421940.02579999994 6349886.4900000002, 421944.69749999978 6349886.5270999996, 421961.53330000024 6349884.4433000004, 421965.2882000003 6349882.2556999996, 421990.56819999963 6349875.8039999995, 422012.08430000022 6349872.6485000001, 422041.04879999999 6349872.8782000002, 422039.18020000029 6349872.8634000001, 422035.47800000012 6349868.3991999999, 422034.56120000035 6349866.1744999997, 422031.81979999971 6349858.3916999996, 422032.67499999981 6349868.3770000003, 422050.26919999998 6349888.4733999996, 422060.51180000044 6349892.9894000003, 422065.16590000037 6349895.2438000003, 422056.80080000032 6349889.6338999998, 422053.09860000014 6349885.1695999997, 422050.12849999964 6349906.2116999999, 422049.96150000021 6349927.2759999996, 422049.68030000012 6349962.7527000001, 422048.57890000008 6349983.8096000003, 422045.62640000042 6350002.6343, 422042.6651999997 6350022.5678000003, 422042.47180000041 6350046.9579999996, 422041.34399999958 6350071.3408000004, 422041.18580000009 6350091.2964000003, 422038.22449999955 6350111.2298999997, 422038.1453999998 6350121.2077000001, 422038.19809999969 6350114.5558000002, 422046.67769999988 6350105.7533, 422026.99459999986 6350113.3581999997, 422008.26339999959 6350118.7533, 421983.92599999998 6350124.1037999997, 421962.34769999981 6350135.0197000001, 421957.51750000007 6350154.9382999996, 421962.99170000013 6350171.6124, 421950.64250000007 6350197.0148999998, 421947.6370000001 6350222.4914999995, 421949.36490000039 6350240.2446999997, 421952.95280000009 6350259.1213999996, 421956.53189999983 6350279.1067000004, 421962.01499999966 6350294.6721999999, 421971.18290000036 6350316.9193000002, 421976.65720000025 6350333.5933999997, 421977.53000000026 6350341.3613999998, 421976.63080000039 6350336.9194, 421975.73159999959 6350332.4774000002, 421955.98639999982 6350347.8426999999, 421928.68680000026 6350373.1265000002, 421912.69660000037 6350386.3041000003, 421892.94240000006 6350402.7779999999, 421878.82969999965 6350414.8617000002, 421870.35850000009 6350422.5554, 421868.4720999999 6350424.7578999996, 421876.28189999983 6350382.6886999998, 421847.54499999993 6350353.6338, 421835.50370000023 6350340.2334000003, 421820.68580000009 6350323.4848999996, 421805.8591 6350307.8449999997, 421791.96690000035 6350292.2125000004, 421773.43809999991 6350272.1081999997, 421758.6026999997 6350257.5767999999, 421743.78500000015 6350240.8282000003, 421734.55599999987 6350226.3414000003, 421725.34470000025 6350209.6372999996, 421714.28230000008 6350190.7011000002, 421703.25519999955 6350167.3301999997, 421688.4907999998 6350143.9296000004, 421691.44400000013 6350125.1048999997, 421694.24710000027 6350125.1272, 421697.04129999969 6350126.2582, 421698.89240000024 6350128.4903999995, 421699.79140000045 6350132.9324000003, 421699.78259999957 6350134.0410000002, 421700.69049999956 6350137.3744000001, 421701.58069999982 6350142.9250999996, 421702.48859999981 6350146.2585000005, 421703.38760000002 6350150.7005000003, 421705.23869999964 6350152.9326999998, 421707.08980000019 6350155.1648000004, 421709.87519999966 6350157.4045000002, 421713.58619999979 6350160.7602000004, 421716.36280000024 6350164.1084000003, 421727.47819999978 6350176.3927999996, 421738.60230000038 6350187.5685000001, 421752.4944000002 6350203.2011000002, 421766.40409999993 6350216.6163999997, 421782.13850000035 6350235.5897000004, 421795.11390000023 6350248.9974999996, 421806.23819999956 6350260.1732000001, 421819.19610000029 6350275.7982000001, 421833.09719999973 6350290.3221000005, 421847.92389999982 6350305.9620000003, 421861.82510000002 6350320.4857000001, 421878.48539999966 6350340.5750000002, 421893.32980000041 6350353.9974999996, 421906.30559999961 6350367.4051999999, 421922.14609999955 6350373.0745999999, 421933.42920000013 6350364.2944, 421927.03809999954 6350345.3954999996, 421917.77350000013 6350335.3435000004, 421895.54200000037 6350310.7752, 421877.01300000027 6350290.6710999999, 421862.18630000018 6350275.0312000001, 421847.35080000013 6350260.5, 421827.87870000023 6350241.4971000003, 421813.05209999997 6350225.8570999997, 421801.93670000043 6350213.5729, 421785.25910000037 6350195.7007999998, 421771.38460000046 6350177.8509, 421758.40050000045 6350165.5516999997, 421744.49969999958 6350151.0278000003, 421729.6911000004 6350133.1704000002, 421713.93929999974 6350116.4143000003, 421699.11309999973 6350100.7741999999, 421681.51040000003 6350081.7857999997, 421666.66660000011 6350068.3629000001, 421658.3546000002 6350056.1008000001, 421652.94280000031 6350031.6659000004, 421654.06259999983 6350008.3918000003, 421661.51099999994 6350011.7773000002, 421663.32670000009 6350018.4440000001, 421666.06790000014 6350026.2269000001, 421665.1512000002 6350024.0022, 421665.16889999993 6350021.7849000003, 421675.36730000004 6350031.8446000004, 421689.26779999956 6350046.3685999997, 421703.15950000007 6350062.0012999997, 421717.99450000003 6350076.5327000003, 421734.67179999966 6350094.4050000003, 421748.55480000004 6350111.1462000003, 421759.67889999971 6350122.3218999999, 421774.51410000026 6350136.8532999996, 421789.34929999989 6350151.3846000005, 421803.25009999983 6350165.9084999999, 421817.15110000037 6350180.4324000003, 421833.82870000042 6350198.3043999998, 421847.72090000007 6350213.9369000001, 421861.62189999968 6350228.4606999997, 421875.51420000009 6350244.0931000002, 421889.41530000046 6350258.6168, 421903.30769999977 6350274.2492000004, 421919.96800000034 6350294.3383999998, 421934.80360000022 6350308.8695, 421944.98500000034 6350321.1462000003, 421957.03519999981 6350333.4376999997, 421975.78440000024 6350325.8255000003, 421970.31010000035 6350309.1513))'
```

I'm trying to generate a buffer of 15 meters with ArcMap 10.4. In the Buffer tool I've used the Full, Round, and Planar methods. With this particular polyline, the results are:
[image]

I want the output to be like this:

[image]

Does somebody know what could be the problem?

Comment: How did you get buffer shown in second picture?

Comment: @FelixIP I made the buffer with the method geodesic

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate your desired output:

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = True
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(32721) #WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_21S
wkt = u'MULTILINESTRING ((421451.00299999956 6350629.8709000004, 421439.96719999984 6350607.6084000003, 421428.77199999988 6350605.3015999999, 421423.3515999997 6350581.9752000002, 421422.61209999956 6350557.5774999997, 421420.98249999993 6350527.6290999996, 421422.11170000024 6350503.2463999996, 421422.31549999956 6350477.7474999996, 421422.51040000003 6350453.3573000003, 421422.70529999956 6350428.9670000002, 421421.97460000031 6350403.4606999997, 421422.19610000029 6350375.7445, 421421.5186999999 6350343.5862999996, 421421.74899999984 6350314.7615, 421422.86060000025 6350292.5959999999, 421423.0820000004 6350264.8798000002, 421423.31240000017 6350236.0549999997, 421422.59949999955 6350208.3313999996, 421422.82100000046 6350180.6151999999, 421422.14360000007 6350148.4568999996, 421423.31709999964 6350118.5308999997, 421434.74210000038 6350092.0130000003, 421449.79810000025 6350078.8287000004, 421455.3953999998 6350079.9820999997, 421454.32820000034 6350096.6043999996, 421452.18499999959 6350130.9574999996, 421451.10890000034 6350148.6884000003, 421450.09480000008 6350158.6586999996, 421449.93539999984 6350178.6144000003, 421450.67489999998 6350203.0120999999, 421450.53320000041 6350220.7504000003, 421450.39149999991 6350238.4888000004, 421451.21079999954 6350252.9086999996, 421451.06020000018 6350271.7556999996, 421450.91849999968 6350289.4939999999, 421450.77680000011 6350307.2324000001, 421450.59970000014 6350329.4052999998, 421451.37469999958 6350349.3684, 421452.16739999969 6350367.1141999997, 421452.97780000046 6350382.6426999997, 421451.89279999956 6350401.4823000003, 421451.71569999959 6350423.6551999999, 421451.56520000007 6350442.5022, 421451.39690000005 6350463.5664999997, 421452.18960000016 6350481.3123000003, 421452.9645999996 6350501.2753999997, 421452.81410000008 6350520.1223999998, 421453.58910000045 6350540.0855, 421454.34640000015 6350562.2659, 421454.1958999997 6350581.1129000001, 421454.06309999991 6350597.7426000005, 421461.49409999978 6350603.3454999998, 421484.89850000013 6350597.9888000004, 421486.02770000044 6350573.6059999997, 421486.18699999992 6350553.6503999997, 421486.34630000032 6350533.6947999997, 421485.58899999969 6350511.5143999998, 421484.82270000037 6350490.4425999997, 421485.01750000007 6350466.0524000004, 421484.25129999965 6350444.9807000002, 421484.5521999998 6350407.2867000001, 421484.75580000039 6350381.7878, 421483.98959999997 6350360.7160999998, 421484.14900000021 6350340.7604, 421483.33849999961 6350325.2319, 421483.49789999984 6350305.2763, 421482.74050000031 6350283.0959000001, 421481.96549999993 6350263.1327999998, 421482.12480000034 6350243.1771, 421482.33729999978 6350216.5696, 421481.57110000029 6350195.4978, 421480.8049999997 6350174.4260999998, 421481.86330000032 6350158.9124999996, 421481.15029999986 6350131.1887999997, 421481.31850000005 6350110.1244999999, 421481.48670000024 6350089.0602000002, 421482.55379999988 6350072.4380000001, 421488.35470000003 6350048.0925000003, 421490.25 6350044.7814999996, 421493.07959999982 6350041.4779000003, 421495.90930000041 6350038.1743999999, 421498.72119999956 6350037.0881000003, 421502.45859999955 6350037.1179999998, 421505.27940000035 6350034.9230000004, 421508.08239999972 6350034.9453999996, 421511.80209999997 6350037.1924999999, 421513.65319999959 6350039.4248000002, 421510.62880000006 6350067.1185999997, 421511.32430000044 6350097.0595000004, 421512.08160000015 6350119.2399000004, 421512.82129999995 6350143.6376, 421511.71879999992 6350164.6944000004, 421512.48500000034 6350185.7662000004, 421513.24239999987 6350207.9466000004, 421513.0831000004 6350227.9022000004, 421513.84929999989 6350248.9740000004, 421513.69010000024 6350268.9296000004, 421512.54330000002 6350295.5296999998, 421512.40170000028 6350313.2680000002, 421512.26900000032 6350329.8976999996, 421513.04409999959 6350349.8607999999, 421512.87600000016 6350370.9250999996, 421513.65110000037 6350390.8881999999, 421514.4084999999 6350413.0685999999, 421515.17470000032 6350434.1403999999, 421514.97119999956 6350459.6392000001, 421514.79430000018 6350481.8121999996, 421514.67040000018 6350497.3332000002, 421514.50229999982 6350518.3975, 421514.32529999968 6350540.5703999996, 421514.15720000025 6350561.6347000003, 421514.94120000023 6350580.4891999997, 421517.62939999998 6350594.9238999998, 421540.01979999989 6350599.5374999996, 421545.69699999969 6350590.7130000005, 421545.89159999974 6350566.3228000002, 421546.01539999992 6350550.8016999997, 421547.14439999964 6350526.4189999998, 421547.32129999995 6350504.2460000003, 421547.49820000026 6350482.0730999997, 421547.60429999977 6350468.7693999996, 421547.63970000017 6350464.3348000003, 421548.71559999976 6350446.6039000005, 421547.81659999955 6350442.1617999999, 421547.08559999987 6350416.6555000003, 421546.31929999962 6350395.5838000001, 421546.48730000015 6350374.5195000004, 421545.7209999999 6350353.4478000002, 421545.88910000026 6350332.3835000005, 421545.13159999996 6350310.2030999996, 421544.35639999993 6350290.2400000002, 421544.39180000033 6350285.8054, 421543.61670000013 6350265.8422999997, 421544.71030000038 6350245.8941000002, 421543.91739999969 6350228.1482999995, 421544.08550000004 6350207.0839999998, 421544.26240000036 6350184.9111000001, 421544.41280000005 6350166.0641000001, 421544.57199999969 6350146.1084000003, 421544.68699999992 6350131.6960000005, 421544.83739999961 6350112.8490000004, 421540.30709999986 6350095.0734000001, 421545.07620000001 6350082.9155000001, 421565.49949999992 6350099.7092000004, 421574.63970000017 6350125.2827000003, 421574.52479999978 6350139.6951000001, 421574.36560000014 6350159.6507000001, 421574.18869999982 6350181.8236999996, 421574.02960000001 6350201.7792999996, 421574.76939999964 6350226.1770000001, 421574.61029999983 6350246.1326000001, 421575.37660000008 6350267.2044000002, 421573.27799999993 6350296.0142999999, 421572.96850000042 6350334.8169, 421572.8004999999 6350355.8811999997, 421573.56689999998 6350376.9528999999, 421573.39890000038 6350398.0171999997, 421573.20440000016 6350422.4073999999, 421574.89630000014 6350444.5953000002, 421573.82050000038 6350462.3262, 421574.57799999975 6350484.5066, 421575.33559999987 6350506.6869000001, 421575.15880000032 6350528.8598999996, 421575.91629999969 6350551.0401999997, 421576.69159999955 6350571.0033, 421577.50219999999 6350586.5318, 421586.76669999957 6350596.5842000004, 421599.84850000031 6350596.6885000002, 421605.63169999979 6350574.5602000002, 421606.69859999977 6350557.9380000001, 421606.81350000016 6350543.5256000003, 421607.01680000033 6350518.0267000003, 421607.16700000037 6350499.1797000002, 421607.33499999996 6350478.1153999995, 421606.58619999979 6350454.8263999997, 421607.67960000038 6350434.8782000002, 421608.77309999987 6350414.9299999997, 421608.94099999964 6350393.8657999998, 421608.20990000013 6350368.3594000004, 421608.36899999995 6350348.4038000004, 421607.73510000017 6350310.7023999998, 421607.89419999998 6350290.7467, 421607.11890000012 6350270.7835999997, 421607.31340000033 6350246.3934000004, 421607.47250000015 6350226.4378000004, 421606.69720000029 6350206.4747000001, 421599.36369999964 6350188.6766999997, 421604.20349999983 6350167.6497, 421620.90720000025 6350182.1962000001, 421631.07039999962 6350196.6904999996, 421635.67150000017 6350205.5969000002, 421636.50870000012 6350217.7994999997, 421635.48599999957 6350228.8784999996, 421635.3004999999 6350252.1601, 421635.16789999977 6350268.7898000004, 421635.94330000039 6350288.7528999997, 421636.57720000017 6350326.4543000003, 421636.40050000045 6350348.6272, 421636.21499999985 6350371.9088000003, 421636.14429999981 6350380.7779999999, 421636.11780000012 6350384.1039000005, 421636.84020000044 6350410.7188999997, 421637.61550000031 6350430.682, 421637.45650000032 6350450.6376, 421636.36309999973 6350470.5857999995, 421636.15110000037 6350497.1933000004, 421636.90000000037 6350520.4823000003, 421637.69299999997 6350538.2280999999, 421638.54789999966 6350548.2133999998, 421658.13499999978 6350552.8043, 421657.31549999956 6350538.3843999999, 421658.35580000002 6350525.0881000003, 421662.17289999966 6350515.1401000004, 421671.21829999983 6350435.3844999997, 421670.51360000018 6350406.5522999996, 421670.54009999987 6350403.2264, 421670.55769999977 6350401.0091000004, 421670.62839999981 6350392.1398999998, 421670.65490000043 6350388.8139000004, 421670.71669999976 6350381.0533999996, 421670.74320000038 6350377.7275, 421669.83530000038 6350374.3941000002, 421669.86180000007 6350371.0681999996, 421669.87939999998 6350368.8509, 421669.91480000038 6350364.4162999997, 421670.89329999965 6350358.8805, 421670.92860000022 6350354.4458999997, 421670.02070000023 6350351.1124999998, 421670.99039999954 6350346.6853999998, 421671.01690000016 6350343.3594000004, 421671.05229999963 6350338.9249, 421670.14439999964 6350335.5915000001, 421669.43960000016 6350306.7592000002, 421665.81689999998 6350292.3169999998, 421655.65350000001 6350277.8227000004, 421666.9896999998 6350262.3909999998, 421679.99149999954 6350272.4730000002, 421692.93149999995 6350290.3156000003, 421697.4709999999 6350306.9824999999, 421696.27180000022 6350340.2344000004, 421697.0736999996 6350356.8716000002, 421693.1595999999 6350379.0147000002, 421684.61770000029 6350395.5774999997, 421676.97479999997 6350416.5822000001, 421671.20949999988 6350436.4932000004, 421673.88019999955 6350453.1452000001, 421698.11270000041 6350461.0992000001, 421717.94680000003 6350434.6479000002, 421724.62880000006 6350416.9616999999, 421728.48990000039 6350401.4704, 421720.29220000003 6350374.7959000003, 421695.04609999992 6350376.8123000003, 421687.48269999959 6350387.8393000001, 421677.00129999965 6350413.2562999995, 421672.13509999961 6350437.6092999997, 421685.04879999999 6350458.7778000003, 421698.99409999978 6350467.7585000005, 421697.90079999994 6350487.7067, 421705.2966 6350497.7440999998, 421718.36930000037 6350498.9568999996, 421727.7751000002 6350491.2707000002, 421727.91629999969 6350473.5323999999, 421728.09279999975 6350451.3594000004, 421728.37509999983 6350415.8827999998, 421730.43809999991 6350391.5073999995, 421725.90730000008 6350373.7319, 421719.4637000002 6350361.4846999999, 421722.36390000023 6350349.3119000001, 421740.03780000005 6350359.4309999999, 421754.87330000009 6350373.9623999996, 421759.32469999976 6350401.7156999996, 421758.26680000033 6350417.2293999996, 421758.12569999974 6350434.9676999999, 421758.91009999998 6350453.8221000005, 421759.71219999995 6350470.4592000004, 421758.65429999959 6350485.9729000004, 421766.9757000003 6350497.1261999998, 421788.5549999997 6350486.2106999997, 421791.48170000035 6350470.7120000003, 421791.60510000028 6350455.1908999998, 421791.69330000039 6350444.1045000004, 421785.30240000039 6350425.2054000003, 421799.34480000008 6350421.9910000004, 421808.59169999976 6350434.2604, 421860.90890000015 6350435.7850000001, 421865.66009999998 6350425.8443, 421861.11149999965 6350410.2861000001, 421850.03100000042 6350393.5673000002, 421838.01609999966 6350376.8410999998, 421822.29899999965 6350355.6505000005, 421810.27539999969 6350340.0329, 421799.21270000003 6350321.0966999996, 421789.97470000014 6350307.7187000001, 421777.95999999996 6350290.9923, 421765.95419999957 6350273.1573999999, 421752.07969999965 6350255.3075000001, 421740.06520000007 6350238.5811000001, 421725.36230000015 6350207.4199999999, 421718.00210000016 6350192.9480999997, 421699.52660000045 6350166.1918000001, 421687.52109999955 6350148.3567000004, 421677.42850000039 6350124.9933000002, 421672.01659999974 6350100.5584000004, 421666.56950000022 6350080.5581, 421657.46439999994 6350050.5500999996, 421652.95160000026 6350030.5573000005, 421648.44770000037 6350009.4556999998, 421644.94000000041 6349980.6010999996, 421641.31749999989 6349966.1589000002, 421640.55979999993 6349943.9785000002, 421650.9171000002 6349934.0826000003, 421685.54090000037 6349927.7061999999, 421708.92599999998 6349924.5663000001, 421735.13179999962 6349919.2313000001, 421751.97640000004 6349916.0392000005, 421773.51040000003 6349910.6670000004, 421797.82100000046 6349908.6430000002, 421819.35489999969 6349903.2706000004, 421842.73110000044 6349901.2390999999, 421867.94070000015 6349903.6568999998, 421892.25999999978 6349900.5239000004, 421911.93400000036 6349894.0279000001, 421915.67140000034 6349894.0575999999, 421919.4263000004 6349891.8700000001, 421923.18130000029 6349889.6824000003, 421926.92750000022 6349888.6034000004, 421931.60800000001 6349887.5318999998, 421940.02579999994 6349886.4900000002, 421944.69749999978 6349886.5270999996, 421961.53330000024 6349884.4433000004, 421965.2882000003 6349882.2556999996, 421990.56819999963 6349875.8039999995, 422012.08430000022 6349872.6485000001, 422041.04879999999 6349872.8782000002, 422039.18020000029 6349872.8634000001, 422035.47800000012 6349868.3991999999, 422034.56120000035 6349866.1744999997, 422031.81979999971 6349858.3916999996, 422032.67499999981 6349868.3770000003, 422050.26919999998 6349888.4733999996, 422060.51180000044 6349892.9894000003, 422065.16590000037 6349895.2438000003, 422056.80080000032 6349889.6338999998, 422053.09860000014 6349885.1695999997, 422050.12849999964 6349906.2116999999, 422049.96150000021 6349927.2759999996, 422049.68030000012 6349962.7527000001, 422048.57890000008 6349983.8096000003, 422045.62640000042 6350002.6343, 422042.6651999997 6350022.5678000003, 422042.47180000041 6350046.9579999996, 422041.34399999958 6350071.3408000004, 422041.18580000009 6350091.2964000003, 422038.22449999955 6350111.2298999997, 422038.1453999998 6350121.2077000001, 422038.19809999969 6350114.5558000002, 422046.67769999988 6350105.7533, 422026.99459999986 6350113.3581999997, 422008.26339999959 6350118.7533, 421983.92599999998 6350124.1037999997, 421962.34769999981 6350135.0197000001, 421957.51750000007 6350154.9382999996, 421962.99170000013 6350171.6124, 421950.64250000007 6350197.0148999998, 421947.6370000001 6350222.4914999995, 421949.36490000039 6350240.2446999997, 421952.95280000009 6350259.1213999996, 421956.53189999983 6350279.1067000004, 421962.01499999966 6350294.6721999999, 421971.18290000036 6350316.9193000002, 421976.65720000025 6350333.5933999997, 421977.53000000026 6350341.3613999998, 421976.63080000039 6350336.9194, 421975.73159999959 6350332.4774000002, 421955.98639999982 6350347.8426999999, 421928.68680000026 6350373.1265000002, 421912.69660000037 6350386.3041000003, 421892.94240000006 6350402.7779999999, 421878.82969999965 6350414.8617000002, 421870.35850000009 6350422.5554, 421868.4720999999 6350424.7578999996, 421876.28189999983 6350382.6886999998, 421847.54499999993 6350353.6338, 421835.50370000023 6350340.2334000003, 421820.68580000009 6350323.4848999996, 421805.8591 6350307.8449999997, 421791.96690000035 6350292.2125000004, 421773.43809999991 6350272.1081999997, 421758.6026999997 6350257.5767999999, 421743.78500000015 6350240.8282000003, 421734.55599999987 6350226.3414000003, 421725.34470000025 6350209.6372999996, 421714.28230000008 6350190.7011000002, 421703.25519999955 6350167.3301999997, 421688.4907999998 6350143.9296000004, 421691.44400000013 6350125.1048999997, 421694.24710000027 6350125.1272, 421697.04129999969 6350126.2582, 421698.89240000024 6350128.4903999995, 421699.79140000045 6350132.9324000003, 421699.78259999957 6350134.0410000002, 421700.69049999956 6350137.3744000001, 421701.58069999982 6350142.9250999996, 421702.48859999981 6350146.2585000005, 421703.38760000002 6350150.7005000003, 421705.23869999964 6350152.9326999998, 421707.08980000019 6350155.1648000004, 421709.87519999966 6350157.4045000002, 421713.58619999979 6350160.7602000004, 421716.36280000024 6350164.1084000003, 421727.47819999978 6350176.3927999996, 421738.60230000038 6350187.5685000001, 421752.4944000002 6350203.2011000002, 421766.40409999993 6350216.6163999997, 421782.13850000035 6350235.5897000004, 421795.11390000023 6350248.9974999996, 421806.23819999956 6350260.1732000001, 421819.19610000029 6350275.7982000001, 421833.09719999973 6350290.3221000005, 421847.92389999982 6350305.9620000003, 421861.82510000002 6350320.4857000001, 421878.48539999966 6350340.5750000002, 421893.32980000041 6350353.9974999996, 421906.30559999961 6350367.4051999999, 421922.14609999955 6350373.0745999999, 421933.42920000013 6350364.2944, 421927.03809999954 6350345.3954999996, 421917.77350000013 6350335.3435000004, 421895.54200000037 6350310.7752, 421877.01300000027 6350290.6710999999, 421862.18630000018 6350275.0312000001, 421847.35080000013 6350260.5, 421827.87870000023 6350241.4971000003, 421813.05209999997 6350225.8570999997, 421801.93670000043 6350213.5729, 421785.25910000037 6350195.7007999998, 421771.38460000046 6350177.8509, 421758.40050000045 6350165.5516999997, 421744.49969999958 6350151.0278000003, 421729.6911000004 6350133.1704000002, 421713.93929999974 6350116.4143000003, 421699.11309999973 6350100.7741999999, 421681.51040000003 6350081.7857999997, 421666.66660000011 6350068.3629000001, 421658.3546000002 6350056.1008000001, 421652.94280000031 6350031.6659000004, 421654.06259999983 6350008.3918000003, 421661.51099999994 6350011.7773000002, 421663.32670000009 6350018.4440000001, 421666.06790000014 6350026.2269000001, 421665.1512000002 6350024.0022, 421665.16889999993 6350021.7849000003, 421675.36730000004 6350031.8446000004, 421689.26779999956 6350046.3685999997, 421703.15950000007 6350062.0012999997, 421717.99450000003 6350076.5327000003, 421734.67179999966 6350094.4050000003, 421748.55480000004 6350111.1462000003, 421759.67889999971 6350122.3218999999, 421774.51410000026 6350136.8532999996, 421789.34929999989 6350151.3846000005, 421803.25009999983 6350165.9084999999, 421817.15110000037 6350180.4324000003, 421833.82870000042 6350198.3043999998, 421847.72090000007 6350213.9369000001, 421861.62189999968 6350228.4606999997, 421875.51420000009 6350244.0931000002, 421889.41530000046 6350258.6168, 421903.30769999977 6350274.2492000004, 421919.96800000034 6350294.3383999998, 421934.80360000022 6350308.8695, 421944.98500000034 6350321.1462000003, 421957.03519999981 6350333.4376999997, 421975.78440000024 6350325.8255000003, 421970.31010000035 6350309.1513))'
polyline = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt,sr)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polyline,r"IN_MEMORY\fcLine")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(polyline,r"IN_MEMORY\fcBuffer","15 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL","#","GEODESIC")
```

[image: Output]